# Nested for loop logic

Tags: c, for-loop, logic, nested-loops

I am trying to accomplish the following using nested for loops (C language):

```
    a[0] = b[0][0];
    a[1] = b[1][0];
    a[2] = b[1][1];
    a[3] = b[2][0];
    a[4] = b[2][1];
    a[5] = b[2][2];
    a[6] = b[3][0];
    a[7] = b[3][1];
    a[8] = b[3][2];
    a[9] = b[3][3];
```

I have this:

```
    for (j=0; j<3; ++j)
        for (k=0; k<j; ++k)
            a[i] = b[j][k];
```

I think I need this:

```
    for (i=0; i<9; ++i)
```

but I'm having trouble working out where to put it. Any help with the logic appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two fixes.

- include a counter
- make your bound check inclusive

Illustrated:

```
int i=0;
for (j = 0; j <= 3; ++j)
    for (k = 0; k <= j; ++k)
        a[i++] = b[j][k];
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/mrgN5A)

Answer (score 1):

You were so close! This should do it:

```
i=0;
for (j=0; j<3; ++j)
    for (k=0; k<j; ++k)
        a[i++] = b[j][k];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increment a variable inside the nested for loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (j=0; j<3; ++j)
    for (k=0; k<j; ++k)
        a[i++] = b[j][k];
```